# Divide number into equal parts such that none of the parts exceed another number

Tags: javascript, math

Pretty much the title; I'm looking for a way to take a number (say 78, for example) and divide it into the minimum number of equal parts that don't exceed another number (say 25, for example). The number of parts doesn't matter, it should just be as small as possible - this means that the resulting numbers should all be as large as possible.

For some context, the reason I want to do this is to work with even text splitting. The messaging service I'm working with only allows 25 lines per message, so I split my text into multiple messages, but I don't want to have messages with only one or two lines. To this end, I'd like to split the text every `n` lines, where `n` is as close to 25 as possible and creates as even of a split across the messages as possible. The number of resulting messages doesn't matter at all, though, so it's not a concern.

Comment: post what you've tried

Comment: Sounding off in agreement with @AlwaysSunny -- you need to show some code of what you've already tried. [ask]

Comment: I'll point you in the right direction -- you'll probably want to use the [Math Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), and I believe that [the modulus operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp) will also be useful.

Comment: I would post what I'd already tried... If I had any idea where to start. I'm decent at math, but I've never been very good at actually devising a formula or process for these sorts of things. If I knew where to start, I could probably bumble my way through it until I hit something decent, but sadly, I don't.

Comment: This is basic math. Using your numbers and integer math: 78 / 25 = 3, with a remainder of 3. If 3 lines is less than your minimum, you need 4 messages. 78 / 4 = 19, with a remainder of 2. You can split that 2 across individual messages (the hard way), which would mean 2 messages of 20 lines and 2 of 19, or the easy way (1 message of 21 lines and 3 of 19). If the remainder of the first divisision is more than your minimum, the question is simpler. 3 messages of 25 lines + 1 of the remainder. This isn't a programming question.

Comment: As I stated in the post: I want to divide the messages *as evenly as possible*. Not have a little leftover with whatever isn't used by the first messages, but to even the messages out as much as possible.

Comment: @KenWhite It is a programming question; doing that effectively is not as simple as it sounds. 78 isn't a hard number - it can change, fluctuate, be technically any number at all, thus I can't simply throw in a basic equation like that. It's just not flexible enough.

Comment: Yes, you can. It's simple integer and modulo operations. I do it on a daily basis in production code, with some batch processing that allows a maximum of 600 operations per batch. As I said, basic math, and the implementation in code is simple (especially if you use the *easy* option I described). Using your own numbers was a simple way of explaining the math; whether it's 78 or 7008, the logic is the same. Plug in 100 in place of 78, and step through the calculation I explained; do it on paper with a pencil. Then plug in 127 and do it again. If it's still not clear, enroll in a math class.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you might want to look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap

Answer (score 1):

After some blind bumbling, I managed to solve the issue.

```
out = [list]

if(list.split("\n").length > 25) {
  n = list.split("\n").length
  x = Math.floor(n / 25)
  y = n / x
  while(y > 25) {
    x += 1
    y = n / x
  }

  out = []
  while(list) {
    l25 = list.split(/\r?\n/, Math.ceil(y)).join("\n")
    list = list.slice(l25.length)
    out.push(l25)
  }
}

// Send each value in out as a separate message
```

Where `list` is the string to split and `out` is the resulting array of strings.